# FFmpeg transcode MP4 to RTSP result in Non-monotonous DTS

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to transcode MP4 to RTSP,So I excute this command, but the RTSP still exist non-monotonous DTS:

```
ffmpeg.exe -re   -fflags +genpts -i .\orange.mp4 -c copy -f rtsp rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/live
```

Is there any solution can fix this problem?